# Confirmation with SweetAlert, Vue & Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sweetalert

I'm trying delete my data after confirmation and for that I want to use [sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/).

## 1

If I use simple alert like:

```
deletePage(index) {
 if (confirm("Do you really want to delete it?")) {
   let page = this.pages[index];
   axios.delete(`/api/pagedelete/${page.id}`).then(response => {
      this.pages.splice(index, 1);
   });
 }
},
```

**Works fine**

## 2

When I want use sweetalert like:

```
deletePage(index) {
  let page = this.pages[index];
                swal({ 
                    title: "Are you sure ?",
                    text: "You will not be able to recover this page !",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it !",
                    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel !",
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    closeOnCancel: false 
                }, 
                function(isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                            axios.delete(`/api/pagedelete/${page.id}`).then(response => {
                                this.pages.splice(index, 1);
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            swal("Cancelled", "Your page has not been deleted !", "error");   
                        }
                    }
                );
}
```

**Doesn't work!**

Error I get is:

```
uncaught exception: SweetAlert: Unexpected 2nd argument (function (isConfirm) {
 var _this2 = this;
 if (isConfirm) {
 axios.delete('/api/pagedelete/' + page.id).then(function (response) {
 _this2.pages.splice(index, 1);
 });
 } else {
 swal("Cancelled", "Your page has not been deleted !", "error");
 }
 })
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation shows it using promises for confirmation](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises):

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```

Your example would then be:

```
deletePage(index) {
  let page = this.pages[index];
  swal({ 
    title: "Are you sure ?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this page !",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it !",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel !",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false 
  }).then((confirmed) => {
    if (confirmed) {
      axios.delete(`/api/pagedelete/${page.id}`).then(response => {
        this.pages.splice(index, 1);
      });
    } else {
      swal("Cancelled", "Your page has not been deleted !", "error");   
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it working however i don't have cancel button, why?

Comment: I think you're using an older API. Try changing your code to use the options from the first example, specifically `buttons: true`.